# JAXB processing of XMLElement annotation

Tags: java, jaxb

How does JAXB process the `@XmlElement` annotation.

Is the source code of this process available somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

This will be done by your JAXB provider. For Eclipselink Moxy it is on [GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/tree/master/moxy/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy).